# Possible to add new list entries via HTML in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a race database to track the positions of runners upon finish of a race. I'm only tracking the top 5 finishers. My goal is to have 5 inputs on the race Create page (with their numbers 1-5), where I just have to select the runner in each spot and save to the database. So I am able to then filter through races, then by position, and then by runner, for example.

I'm stuck as to how to create exactly 5 new positions and display them and their accompanying runner dropdowns in the HTML. Do you create the list entries in the "Get: Races/Create?", or is this possible via HTML, maybe setting the position values. I had originally though to create 5 database entries for my Positions table for the 5 positionNumbers - but I thought that would attach the number to the ID and cause issues?

I can't figure out what to look for to find the solution I'm after.

I have a Race model which looks like this:

```
public class Race
{
    public Race()
    {
        Positions = new List<Position>();
    }

    public int RaceId { get; set; }

    public int TrackId { get; set; }
    public Track Track { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

And the accompanying Positions model looks like this:

```
public class Position
{
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public int PositionNumber { get; set; }


    public int RaceId { get; set; }
    public int RunnerId { get; set; }
    public Race Race { get; set; }
    public Runner Runner { get; set; }
}
```

Bit of a newbie at EF Core, so apologies for bad explanations

Requirement: The end result I'm looking for is something akin to this for the Race Create page:
[image]

And then this on the Edit page:
[image]

Comment: HTML is a frontend language. It is not able to do any interactions or in this case, connect to any database. I think what you meant was to use JavaScript or form post?

Comment: `how to create exactly 5 new positions and display them and their accompanying runner dropdowns in the HTML` Please clarify more about your requirement, so that we can understand it better.

Comment: @FeiHan I added 2 images that better show what I'm trying to achieve. Essentially I need to add 5 positions to the Race model, and assign a Runner to them. Unsure how to bring that into the Create view page and save that to the database

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the EF side of things, it's pretty smart with figuring out references, provided that you have configured the EF classes correctly using [ForeignKey] attributes for example.

```
public class Position
{
   public int RaceId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("RaceId")]
   public Race Race { get; set; }

   // ... other stuff in the class
}
```

Example 1 - you can directly reference the RaceId

```
// assuming there is a race with ID 1 in the DB

// Create 5 position objects referencing RaceId 1
var pos1 = new Position { PositionNumber = 1, RaceId = 1, RunnerID = 101 }
var pos2 = new Position { PositionNumber = 2, RaceId = 1, RunnerID = 102 }
var pos3 = new Position { PositionNumber = 3, RaceId = 1, RunnerID = 103 }
var pos4 = new Position { PositionNumber = 4, RaceId = 1, RunnerID = 104 }
var pos5 = new Position { PositionNumber = 5, RaceId = 1, RunnerID = 105 }
```

Example 2 - you can reference a Race object

```
// Create a new race
var race2 = new Race();

// Create 5 position objects referencing the newly created race
var pos1 = new Position { PositionNumber = 1, Race = race2 , RunnerID = 101 }
var pos2 = new Position { PositionNumber = 2, Race = race2 , RunnerID = 102 }
var pos3 = new Position { PositionNumber = 3, Race = race2 , RunnerID = 103 }
var pos4 = new Position { PositionNumber = 4, Race = race2 , RunnerID = 104 }
var pos5 = new Position { PositionNumber = 5, Race = race2 , RunnerID = 105 }

// In this example:
// EF will automatically assign the ID generated for race2
// to the RaceId column of pos1,2,3,4,5
```

And usually you need to tell EF that these are new objects

```
DbContext.Entry(race2).State = EntityState.Added;
DbContext.Entry(pos1).State = EntityState.Added;
// and so on
```

And then save it all

```
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Let me know if that helps or not. I suspect your question is much bigger than just the EF side of things. But I'll start with this and see where it leads.